# React.js: Populate listbox using axios POST request

Tags: reactjs

I'm using a library called 'react-dual-listbox' for my listbox needs

I've had success in showing the listbox with hardcoded components

However, if its from an API response, I can't render it properly

ProfileMaintenancePage.js

```
    import 'react-dual-listbox/lib/react-dual-listbox.css';
    import DualListBox from 'react-dual-listbox';

    const [optionsListbox, setOptionsListbox] = useState([]);

    const retrieveModulesList = useCallback(() => {
        ProfileMaintenanceService.retrieveModulesList()
        .then((response) => {
          console.log("ProfileMaintenancePage - retrieveModules response.data >>> " + response.data)
          console.log("ProfileMaintenancePage - retrieveModules JSON.stringify(response.data) >>> " + JSON.stringify(response.data))
          setOptionsListbox(response.data);
        }).catch((err) => {
          console.log("ProfileMaintenancePage - retrieveModules catch >>> " + err)
        })
      });

    useEffect(() => {
        retrieveModulesList();
      }, []);

    const newOptionsListbox = optionsListbox.map(({MODULE, DESCRIPTION}) => ({
        label: MODULE,
        value: DESCRIPTION
      }))

    return (

    <DualListBox
                    options={newOptionsListbox}
                    selected={selected}
                    onChange={onChange}
                    showHeaderLabels={true}
                />

    )
```

ProfileMaintenanceService.js

```
import axios from 'axios'

const API_URL_RETRIEVE_MODULES = 'http://localhost:8080/api/test'

class ProfileMaintenanceService {

    /* API for populating modules in listbox */
    retrieveModulesList() {
        return axios.post(`${API_URL_RETRIEVE_MODULES}`, {
            token: "abc123"
        })
    }

}

export default new ProfileMaintenanceService()
```

I'm not sure what am I missing, since I tried to map the data from the state to the listbox.

Please help.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Nothing's wrong with my code. It was just case sensitivity issue on the JSON and the mapping. Thanks!